# How many options are there to choose $6$ courses from a pool of $13$ courses if at most three of those courses may be in math?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> How many different options are they to choose $6$ courses from $13$ courses pool, ($5$ in Math, $4$ in Physics and $4$ in Computer science), but the maximum courses you can choose in math is $3$?

I thought about $\binom{13}{6} - \binom{5}{4}\binom{9}{2}$.
Basically I took all the options to choose any course without any conditions, and subtract from it the options I choose $4$ courses in math and then $2$ more in any subject (the last one in math included), which gives me a total of $1536$ options.

But the other way to think about it is $\binom{13}{6} - \binom{5}{4}\binom{8}{2}-\binom{5}{5}\binom{8}{1}$.  Again, I'm taking all the options to choose any course without any conditions, but now I subtract from it the options to choose $4$ courses in math and then $2$ courses from the other $2$ subjects and the options to choose $5$ courses in math and $1$ course from the other $2$ subjects, which gives me a total of $1568$ options.

Which answer is the correct one and why?

Comment: What is (4 choose 5) ???

Comment: "*then 2 more in any subject (the last one in math included)*"  This is wrong.  You are incorrectly applying some sort of significance to whether four certain math classes were part of the "originally chosen" math classes versus whether it was from the "leftover".  To correct this, you can break into cases based on if it was four math classes chosen or five math classes chosen.

Comment: Compare to the problem where there are exactly $6$ classes to choose from *and all are math classes!*  We ask how many ways to choose $6$ classes such that $4$ or more of them were math classes.  It should be obvious that the correct answer here is that there is exactly one way to choose the classes... the way where you just pick every class once.  According to your broken logic however, you might have said there are $\binom{6}{4}\cdot \binom{2}{2}$ ways (*pick four math classes first, and then pick two more from what is leftover*).  Your first attempt has the same fundamental flaw.

Comment: you can count : how many options with exactly 0 course of math + how many with 1, + how many with 2 +  how many with 3.  You will know which result is the correct one. There is also another ""rule"" : when you count $C(a,b) -C(c,d) \times C(e,f)$ , generally, you should have a=c+e and b=d+f

Comment: How many options with at-least xxx is always difficult, you should always count : how many options with EXACTLY  xxx

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Number of schedules with 0 math classes:

$8\choose6$

Number of schedules with 1 math class:

$5\choose1$ $8\choose5$

Number of schedules with 2 math classes:

$5\choose2$ $8\choose4$

Number of schedules with 3 math classes:

$5\choose3$ $8\choose3$

Total:

$8\choose6$ $+$ $5\choose1$ $8\choose5$ $+$ $5\choose2$ $8\choose4$   $+$ $5\choose3$ $8\choose3$ $= 1568$

Comment: Thanks, fixed it