# In how many we ways can choose at least three courses (one from each major)?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Note :This question was in our final exam and I didn't know how to approach it.

The question:

In the University there are $6$ six courses in Math, $6$ courses in CS, and $3$ in Physics (each course is different). In how many ways we can choose $6$ courses from the database s.t one course from each major will be chosen?

First, I tried to use Brute-force to see if there is a pattern, but it cannot be done, because if I'm doing Brute-force, I divide by $3$ but it makes us to not handle physics courses at all because there is only one option and they're always in the databases. But that's what I did in the exam so let's look at it again - if we divide by $3$
we need to choose only $3$ courses out of $5$ courses database and it just a regular question with the solution:  $1 \cdot {3 \choose 1} \cdot {3 \choose 1}$
I really didn't know how to approach it, the official solution apply PIE, but I don't understand how to apply PIE, because if we divide to groups, but when I'm trying to do to so, it just separates it to a lot of cases, without applying PIE.

For example,

$A_1$ - there are $3$ courses in physics, $2$ from CS and $1$ from Math

$A_2$ - there are $3$ courses in physics, $1$ from CS and $2$ from Math

And so on...

It looks like too many cases, especially to solve it during exam while I have an average time of $7$ minutes to solve it. I'm sure there is more simple and correct solution for that question.

I know that this question looks similar - [How many options are there to choose $6$ courses from a pool of $13$ courses if at most three of those courses may be in math?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4611689/how-many-options-are-there-to-choose-6-courses-from-a-pool-of-13-courses-if)

But it is a little bit different, and does not use PIE.

Comment: What is PIE?...

Comment: @SisantaChhatoi principle of inclusion-exclusion... which is the suggested approach for such problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggested inclusion-exclusion approach:

There are $6+6+3=15$ courses available.

$\binom{15}{6}$ ways to choose six courses if we don't care about amounts.

Of these, $\binom{9}{6}$ had no math courses and are "bad" for that reason.  Similarly, $\binom{9}{6}$ had no CS courses, and $\binom{12}{6}$ had no physics courses.  We subtract these from our count.

But then, we subtracted too much... specifically those which were void in multiple subjects, which happens specifically when we took only math courses, or took only CS courses (*noting it is impossible to take only physics courses, there aren't enough*)

Our total then is $\binom{15}{6}-\binom{9}{6}-\binom{9}{6}-\binom{12}{6}+\binom{6}{6}+\binom{6}{6}$

---

To be clear, the approach where you first select one from each subject and then fill out the rest after the fact is wrong.  That would have inadvertently given importance to whether something was picked in the first step versus in the remainder.  That would be the count for how many class schedules you could make if you had to specify one from each subject as your "favorite" and would make (Combinatorics (fav), Algebra, Analysis, Geometry, Java (fav), Electromagnetics (fav)) a different outcome than (Combinatorics, Algebra, Analysis (fav), Geometry, Java (fav), Electromagnetics (fav)) despite both consisting of the same classes

Comment: thx for clarifying why I was wrong.